# Want to show total number of specific complaints of logged in user in laravel (blade)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Hey I have different complaints statuses in my table like active, closed etc. I want to total number of active complaints or closed complaints in my dashboard but I dont know how!

this is my controller which works good for total number of complaints to user and to admin:

```
    public function index()
    {
        if(auth()->user()->role=='USER') {
            $total = Complaint::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count();
        } else {
            $total = Complaint::all()->count();
        }

        return view('dashboard', compact('total'));
    }
```

I simply use `{{ $total }}` to show the total number of complaints but now I want to show the total number of active complaints in the dashboard! how can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$totals = DB::table('complains')
             ->select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
             ->groupBy('status')
             ->get();
```